# Keeping Sessions between Jboss AS 7 restarts/deployments

Tags: session, deployment, jboss7.x

We use JBOSS 7 AS and I wondered always if it can be configured so, that the sessions are not lost after restarts or deployments. Are there any possibilities for that, supposing in the session there is no non-serializable data stored ?

Answer (score 0):

Restarts : If you setup a cluster with session replication then your sessions should be served by another jboss instance if the instance you are connected to fails.

Deployments : Deployments generally take a long time (at least more than a few minutes) ; I dont see the point in maintaining session state across deployments.

Comment: 1. we have no clusters: it is about development, and not production. With no cluster: would be possible to persist the sessions somewhere, and on start to load them again? 2. The problem with long deployment times: so far we didn't notice it with our applications (in JBoss 7). The point is not to waste the time with login again and not to make 100 more clicks to come to the correct interface.